# How to position div below previous div and not below the div with largest height

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs...

[image: 3 divs]

if I float the divs to the left, it will look like this..

[image: divs floated left]

Now, I want "Div 3" to be positioned below "Div 2" like so..

[image: correct div placement]

So, I put

> clear: both

to "Div 3" but it ended up looking like this:
[image: misplaced div 3]

"Div 3" went below the div with the largest height which, in this case, is "Div 1".. What should I do to achieve the positioning similar to that of picture 3?

Comment: Does your `div` elements have fixed `width`?

Comment: div widths are all 100px @ROX

Comment: What about the container? What is the width of it?

Comment: well, let's just say, in this example, it is 350px.

Comment: How are the `<div>` dimensions determined? Are they going to change? Will there be other `<div>`s? What is the purpose of the effect you're trying to achieve? These things may affect the types of solutions that'll work for you.

Comment: If your markup is static, it can implement by CSS, but if you have dynamic layout which generates by server-side language, you may need javascript, for example the [isotope jQuery plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html). Is your markup static? or dynamic?

Comment: this is an extremely simple thing to do, as long as you make your head. If your container is 350px width and your elements are 100px width, yet you have 2 columns (hence 2 x 100px + say 20px for margins and borders) it's more than obvious there are at least 120 empty pixels, which of course will be filled by the remaining element in the float. So you either make the containing element wide enough to contain 2 (two) columns, or you make those columns wide enough to fill that element. As simple as that

Comment: my question here is, how do you position the third div so that it will be under "Div 2" and not under "Div 1" @Fabio

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.

First, you can keep everything `float: left` and put a width on the parent container to prevent `Div3` from being placed on the top line. The width will knock it down to the next line below Div2 as long as the paren twidth is >  the width of div1 and div2.

Second, you could absolutely position the divs.

Lastly, if you dont want to do either of those, your best bet is to go with a JavaScript library like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/). These libraries were created because the layout you want is very difficult to achieve in pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use < span > for inline div.

(Cannot add comment, hence answered.)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you expecting?

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="Div1"> </div>
  <div class="Div2"> </div>
  <div class="Div3"> </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    width: 205px;
}
.Div1 {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height:205px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    float: left;
}
.Div2 {
    background: green;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    float: right;
}
.Div3 {
    background: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    float: right;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvijayakumar/m5gqqr7d/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you need 2 outerdivs for that. try this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6tokcv7/)

```
<body>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="div1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="div2"></div>
            <div class="div3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.left, .right {
    float: left;
}

.div1 {
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
}
.div2, .div3 {
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.div3 {
    background: green;
}
```